# No valid crumb error message after logging after migration from jenkins 2.263.4 to 2.277.4

Tags: jenkins

I have this message on windows when I want to connect to jenkins (Active directory plugin).

I just updated from Jenkins 2.263.4 to 2.277.4. jenkins server is run on the same machine, on windows. it is launched and update using jenkins.war file.

I can enter my login and password but after that I have this error message :

```
HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
URI:    /j_spring_security_check
STATUS: 403
MESSAGE:    No valid crumb was included in the request
SERVLET:    Stapler
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.39.v20210325
```

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved after updating active directory plugin from 2.16.1 to 2.25.1
see :
https://community.jenkins.io/t/jenkins-upgrade-error-no-valid-crumb/955